# Angularjs - removing table row (using ngRoute, factory)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory, splice, angularjs-ng-route

I have three html files and trying to insert, remove datas to a table. I have succeeded to insert datas to table, but cannot remove those. I'm thinking that I'm not returning the right value or maybe something else is wrong. any helps please?
(I have commented all the parts related to remove operation)

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>index</title>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,=">
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="papa">
        <li><a href="/1_input">input</a></li>
        <li><a href="/2_output">output</a></li>
    </ul>

   <ng-view></ng-view>

    <script>
    var app1 = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
    app1.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/1_input', {
          controller: 'input_control',
          templateUrl: '/1_input.html'
       })
        .when('/2_output/:name/:kor/:eng/:math', {
          controller: 'output_control',
          templateUrl: '/2_output.html'
        })

        // .when('/2_output', {
        //   controller: 'delete_control',
        //   templateUrl: '/2_output.html'
        // })
        // .when('/2_output/:index', {
        //   controller: 'output_control2',
        //   templateUrl: '/2_output.html'
        // })
        .otherwise({redirectTo:'/1_input'});

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false });
    }]);

    app1.controller('input_control', function($scope, $location, DataService){
        $scope.loadView2 = function(){
            DataService.set($scope.name, $scope.kor, $scope.eng, $scope.math);
          $location.path('/2_output/'+$scope.name+'/'+$scope.kor+'/'+$scope.eng+'/'+$scope.math);
       }
    });
    app1.controller('output_control',function($scope, DataService){
          $scope.list77 = DataService.get();
    });

    // app1.controller('delete_control', function($scope, $location, DataService){
    //  $scope.delete = function(xx){
    //      DataService.delete88(xx);
    //      $location.path('/2_output/'+xx);
    //  }
    // });
    // app1.controller('output_control2',function($scope, DataService){
    //    $scope.list77 = DataService.delete88(xx);
    // });

    app1.factory('DataService', function(){
        var appData = [];
        var appData1 = [];
        function set(data1, data2, data3, data4){
            appData.push({
                id: data1,
                kor: parseInt(data2),
                eng: parseInt(data3),
                math: parseInt(data4),
                tot: parseInt(data2)+parseInt(data3)+parseInt(data4),
                avg: (parseInt(data2)+parseInt(data3)+parseInt(data4))/3
            });
        }
        function get(){return appData}

        // function delete88(xx){
        //  return appData.splice(xx, 1);
        // }
        // //function del_get(){return appData1}

        return{ set:set, get:get/*, delete88:delete88*/}
    })

</script>
```

1_input.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>1_input</title>
</head>

<body>
    name:<input type="text" ng-model="name"/> <br/>
    kor_:<input type="text" ng-model="kor"/> <br/>
    eng_:<input type="text" ng-model="eng"/> <br/>
    math:<input type="text" ng-model="math"/> <br/>
    <br>
    <button ng-click="loadView2()">to output page</button>
 </body>
 </html>
```

2_output.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>2_output</title>
    <style>
      table, th, td{
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid grey;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 5px;
      }
      table tr:nth-child(odd){ background-color: #f2f2f2; }
      table tr:nth-child(eve){ background-color: #ffffff; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>kor</th>
            <th>eng</th>
            <th>math</th>
            <th>tot</th>
            <th>avg</th>
            <!-- <th>del</th> --> 
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="listabc in list77 track by $index">
            <td>{{listabc.id}}</td>
            <td>{{listabc.kor}}</td>
            <td>{{listabc.math}}</td>
            <td>{{listabc.eng}}</td>
            <td>{{listabc.tot}}</td>
            <td>{{listabc.avg}}</td>
            <!-- <td><button ng-click="delete($index)">삭제</button></td> -->
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i don't see any `ng-controller` in the above code

Comment: It is defined in the router. I think this is the problem. Using the same template for both controllers. You should have only one controller, because it cannot decide which is the meant controller it should use!

Comment: @chabeee yeah, you are right. i searched a bit more and i think my problem will be solved if i use ui-router

Comment: ui-router is a great option, but you will have almost the same logic what I mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you load your data. In your delete controller, where do you load `list77` ?